# Intellij does not recognize Scala List operator

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Here is the intellij warning :

[image]

When overing "::" Intellij display this message : Cannot resolve symbol ::

I have scala + sbt plugins correctly installed.

How can i fix this error ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code is incorrect : `::` is a method on `List`, not on `Integer`. Your last element must be an instance of `List`.

Either of those will work :

```
val otherList = 3::2::List(3)
```

or

```
val otherList = 3::2::3::Nil
```

---

Note that `::` is called on `List` and not the `Integer` because it is right-associative.

From the [Scala Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (*Infix Operations*, 6.12.3) :

> The associativity of an operator is determined by the operator’s last
>   character. Operators ending in a colon ‘:’ are right-associative. All
>   other operators are left-associative.